# tableView will crash when reload data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, reloaddata

After I call method getData. I try reload data but it didn't reload data. I don't know why but I can get Data correctly. Oh I set getData at viewDidAppear because I want to get in this view from prev view quickly and User will see loading view and when I completely load data , loading view will disappear and tableview will appear

Here is my simple code

.m

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self getData];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@",con_ad,con_po,depre,other);
    [tableCommon reloadData];
    [bckView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

.h

```
@interface Hoora : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableCommon;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableCommon;
```

I already link Ref. Outlet.

It said it crash at main.m How can I set cell in new data.

I'm sorry. It just show EXE-BAD-ACCESS error

Comment: what error you are getting? there may be many many reason, may you are trying to get deallocated variable in [self getData]

Comment: We need more code to see your problem.

Comment: atleast post the error dude..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another possibility is that your custom cells and/or data source are released. Then the reload TableView method want to access the cells/data source but couldn't get the data -> crash